# FAT 32 usb stick says its full

Tags: windows-7, windows

I'm new to all this,please help if you can. I bought a USB 16GB Verbatim stick before christmas, the brother put on films for me. I plugged it into my TV and it worked away fine. Gave it to my son so he could watch the films,he put it in his xbox. He told me next day that he couldnt get it working. Now i put it on my computer and it says that its 15 gb used with 4.32 gb free,this doesnt add up i know. When i open it, it comes up as empty. Any theories?
Thanks

Windows 7 is the system.

Comment: You will need to use a program to determine what is using the space before we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Xbox uses its own file system which is not recognized by Windows. In order for the Xbox to use the USB device it probably had to configure it when he inserted it. Doing that most likely stored some files on the drive which you can not see.

You can try changing the settings to view hidden and system files in Windows Explorer in order to view the Xbox files to remove them.

Here is how SanDisk says to remove the files using the Xbox; [Deleting Xbox 360 files on a USB flash drive](http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4127/~/deleting-xbox-360-files-on-a-usb-flash-drive). The brand of flash drive is irrelevant to these instructions.

[image]

If you want to start over, you can simply format the flash drive.

Comment: Perfect,Thanks.Only for my son being there i wouldve deleted his drive on the xbox,wouldve been in trouble then. Hee Hee. Thanks again,great help.

Comment: You bet. If you see fit, feel free to mark this as the answer. It also lets other readers know it answered your question.